# Preventing gtk FileChooserDialog calling stat on all files in the directory?

Tags: linux, performance, dialog, gtk

Opening a gtk FileChooserDialog is painfully slow for nfs directories containing many files. strace shows a lot of time calling "stat". About 5 calls for each of the files in the directory. How can we switch off the calls to 'stat' and just show a list of filenames without the modification time?

We're using operating Redhat enterprise 4, x86_64, Linux 2.6.9-42.0.8.ELsmp and FileChooser is coming from: /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.400.13 . A test program opens a FileChooserDialog and takes 10 seconds to appear, compared to about 25 ms for 'ls' to list the same directory.

Our eclipse application being crippled by this file selector issue...

Comment: I've noticed this lag time also. Its really annoying when you go to /usr/bin to tell firefox what app to use to open a file and it lags for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gtk+ and gnome team have a [bug](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=310642) report related to this issue, at least since 2005. Recent and future changes in the gnome core libraries will hopefully improve the performance.
This issue can be aggravated if you have any bookmarks to network drives in the filechooser menu.

Answer (score 0):

The GTK file open dialog is most probably stat(2)ting all files in the directory. It is an eqivalent of `ls -l` on the directory, and it should run about that slowly. The output of `ls | cat` (which is significantly faster) might not be enough, because that one cannot distinguish files from directories.

I'd suggest measuring `ls | cat`, `ls -l` and and the GTK file open dialog. If the GTK file open dialog is a lot slower than `ls -l`, then there is something wrong with GTK (not NFS). I'd run the GTK application through `strace`, and see what is slow. If the GTK file open dialog has about the same speed as `ls -l`, I don't think it can be made faster -- perhaps NFS mount flags can be tweaked, NFS clients and servers upgraded, or it is possible to switch to a faster infrastructure such as Samba.

Comment: ls -l is also slow, so the underlying problem is how to navigate on a dodgy file system. The point is, I don't care whether the 14027 files which I can't see in a file selector are directories or not, I only need to know for the first 20 or so that fit on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Is the directory mounted noatime?  That may help with the stat since the atime for each file will be updated with the stat.

You'll need to remount the nfs mount with -o noatime in order to turn off atime updating.

Comment: cat /proc/mounts shows: 
nfs rw,v3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,hard,intr,tcp,lock,addr=gx.hidd.en 0 0

So no? We tried chattr and got "Inappropriate ioctl...". Can we change this 'noatime' from a user account when our application runs?

Using 'ls' | head takes 40 milliseconds, compared to 10 seconds for a GTK file selector. The problem is GTK is doing something which is not needed and not wanted and we'd prefer to stop that altogether instead of making it less slow.

Thanks a lot for your suggestion - I shall forward it to the sysadmins...

Comment: stat(2) doesn't affect atime