# How to disable icons on GTK file dialog?

Tags: linux, gtk

I have a peculiar FUSE filesystem that is quite slow by itself, and browsing it with this dialog is tedious at best. This happens because the dialog opens every single file in a directory before showing its contents to the user, maybe because it's trying to decide which icons to show.
Is there a way to tell a GtkFileChooserDialog to don't bother with showing the icons?

[image]

(This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809560/preventing-gtk-filechooserdialog-calling-stat-on-all-files-in-the-directory) but it's not the same)

I'm on Xubuntu 10.04, GTK 2.20

Answer (score 0):

Run `gconf-editor` and enable the key: `/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/disable_all`.

Comment: Unfortunately that's for "Disable all external thumbnailer programs, independent on whether they are independently disabled/enabled", while my problem is with the icons that GTK places beside every file to show their type, not their preview. I'll clarify the question. Thanks all the same!

Comment: Oh, then I don't think icons are your problem, determining the file type should be quite a snappy action. Try in a terminal ` file *` while being in that directory. It shouldn't take long to process every file, but it's not the case, then yes, determining the file type might be your problem. Unfortunately, without doing a bit of profiling, it's going to be hard guessing what exactly is really slowing down the display.

Comment: Do you mean that GTK uses libmagic (the same as `file` IIRC) to guess the file type? Anyway I'll try, thanks :)

Comment: Don't know how GTK determines the file type, I just meant that if `file` is already slow, don't expect quick results in the file chooser ;-)